# Nginx access log with milli seconds

Tags: linux, nginx, logging

Currently Im having the time in my access logs as

```
2018-03-20T04:11:42-07:00
```

Actually Im bit confused on this notation. What is the T part about? How can I add the time part with milliseconds ?

Comment: "T" separates Date and Time. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: oh ok. How can I add milliseconds to the normal HH:MM:SS format ?

Comment: That would be an issue of the nginx manuals. I don't know anything about that.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/q/732395 . It's a bit old, so you may want to verify it against nginx manuals/releasenotes ... other forums.